# Numpy Matmul while ignoring first axis

Tags: python, numpy, array-broadcasting

I have a bunch of 5-dimensional vectors of shape `(5,)` in a 2-dimensional array of shape `(1000, 5)`, each of which which I want to multiply by a matrix of shape `(6, 5)`.

I would have assumed that broadcasting would allow me to do

```
A = np.random.rand(1000, 5)
B = np.random.rand(1, 6, 5) # empty axis for broadcasting
np.matmul(B, A)
```

but this doesn't work properly.

Is there a way to do this kind of multiplication so that `np.matmul(B, A)` produces an output of shape `(1000, 6)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you actually have this:

```
A = np.random.rand(1000, 5)
B = np.random.rand(6, 5)
```

Then a much easier way to do this operation is

```
A @ B.T
```

or

```
A.dot(B.T)
```

Remember matrix multiplaction is an inner product, so the inner dimensions must match (in this case, be `5`).  By transposing `.T` you swap the `6` and `5` dimensions to get them in the right order.

If you don't want to play with the order (say you have a ton of dimensions), you can also always set the axes explicitly with `np.einsum`

```
np.einsum('ij,kj->ik', A, B, optimize = True)
```

`optimize` makes this almost as fast as `.dot()` or `@`, but currently only works when you don't need to broadcast a dimension on your inputs (you don't here).

Answer (score 0):

I just figured the answer out. The solution is to format the arrays as

```
A = np.ones((100, 5, 1))
B = np.ones((6, 5))
np.matmul(B, A)
```

and the broadcasting comes out all right. Hope this helps!